# Is there a name for this construction on two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A,B$ be two 2x2 matrices. Let $A_i$ refer to the ith row of $A$ (resp. for $B$). I'm interested in the 2x1 vector

$$v = \binom{A_1 \cdot B_1}{A_2 \cdot B_2}$$

or expanded,

$$v = \binom{A_{11}B_{11} + A_{12}B_{12}}{A_{21}B_{21}+A_{22}B_{22}}$$

Question: does this have a name in the literature? Is there a way to describe $v$ purely in terms of $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens to be the diagonal of a matrix product
$$
\mathrm{diag}( A B^T ) = \mathrm{diag}\left( \begin{pmatrix} A_{11}B_{11} + A_{12} B_{12} & A_{11} B_{21} + A_{12} B_{22} \\ A_{21}B_{11} + A_{22} B_{12} & A_{21} B_{21} + A_{22} B_{22} \end{pmatrix} \right) = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11}B_{11} + A_{12} B_{12} \\ A_{21} B_{21} + A_{22} B_{22} \end{pmatrix}. 
$$

Of course, the geometric meaning is not obvious. Maybe remotely related is the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) which is the trace of $A B^T$. But I'm not sure if that helps...

Comment: You can also write this using the all-ones vector $(\tt1)$ and the Hadamard product $(\odot)$ as $$\large{v=(A\odot B)\,{\tt1}}$$